# Order of stylesheets with scss, webpacker and rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using the webpacker gem (v4.0.7) for assets as is default in Rails 6.

My stylesheet assets are loading via app/javascripts/stylesheets/application.scss file

However, the order of listing of stylesheet assets in this file is not reflected in the compiled css in development, e.g.

application.scss:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
@import "./theme/style.css";
```

And when I load the page I see the `bootstrap` stylesheet take precedence over `style.css`:

[image: screenshot of stylesheets from developer tools in chrome]

Is there a way to control the order of inclusion?

Comment: Are you facing some problem related to the order of the assets compilation?

Comment: @DimitriusLachi  Yes, I updated my question with more details

Comment: I guess this might be a scss problem as opposed to webpack(er). I'm investigating further

Answer (score 2):

Figured this one out and it's to do with scss rather than webpack(er)

In my application.scss the files I was importing were .css files which were therefore not compiling as such. Changing these to .scss files meant that they were compiled in the order specified.

(This is the article that ultimately led me to a fix: https://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-the-import-directive/)